# Ordering in a drop down list

Tags: java, wordpress, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

In my Wordpress site, I created a drop down field with values starting from 80 to 230. However, when viewing this list, it starts from 100, 110, 120 and the numbers 80 and 90 are at the end. How can I fix it and have that list starting from 80, 90, 100, 110 etc ?  Code is here: https://exal.gr/product/%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%B3%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF-%CE%B4%CE%B9%CF%86%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF-%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%B3%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF-kmg/ 
Image with the problem is here: 
https://exal.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/dropdown.jpg

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the dropdown is configured to sort the entries by their string representation, rather than their integer value. Isn't there some sort of option to choose the dropdown as being of integers?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. 
These are attributes values that aren't ordering correctly 
Under Products menu => Attributes => Edit width attribute => I changed Default sort order   to be “Name(Numeric)” instead of “Name”.